# ASP.NET MVC plugin architecture & deployments

Tags: msbuild, publish, msdeploy

For a customer we have an ASP.NET MVC plugin architecture consisting of:
- 1 core web application (this is the root web application in IIS)
- X plugins for which the content (views, css, scripts) are deployed in a sub folder (Areas)
The assemblies of the plugins are deployed in the root bin folder

The plugins are created by separate teams and these teams should be able to deploy a package to a server.
The package (ran by administrators) should make sure the plugin is deployed correctly (in a sub folder of the core) and the dll files should be deployed in the root bin. 
I guess a deployment package should be created.

How can this be done or what are good practices around this?
How can I customize the way a package will be interpreted (MSBuild)?

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a late answer, however I have been using a method of creating 'pluggable' areas similar to that discussed [here](http://nileshhirapra.blogspot.ca/2012/02/aspnet-mvc-pluggable-application.html) and [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/cokobware/archive/2013/01/15/asp.net-mvc-4-pluggable-application-modules.aspx).

What these articles talk about is a method to turn areas into separate web projects which can then be bin deployed with the original web app when required.

I have extended their methods with a custom `ViewEngine` which inherits from the Razor view engine, to look for Views in a specified folder location (I named this folder 'Modules'). This is dynamic based upon whether the modules are included or not (I search for modules in the Modules folder on app_start).

Hope this helps!